# Spinner with different display and return value

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I want to create a spinner that displaying month, for example "January, February, etc". From that spinner,  I want to pass the value selected in "1, 2, etc" rather than what spinner showed. Any suggestion to solve that problem?

Comment: That can be done, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourItemsArray);
    adapter_state
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    yourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter_state);
    yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int position = yourSpinner
                    .getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
            // position is your selected position
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use Spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1; adding 1  because it starts from 0,1,2...

Answer (score 0):

Create a pojo class:

```
public class SpinnerUtils {
     public SpinnerUtils(String spinnerText, int value) {
         this.spinnerText = spinnerText;
         this.value = value;
     }

     public String getSpinnerText() {
         return spinnerText;
     }

     public int getValue() {
         return value;
     }

     public String toString() {
         return spinnerText;
     }

     String spinnerText;
     int value;
 }
```

Then:

```
SpinnerUtils items[]=new SpinnerUtils[array.length()];
items[i] = new SpinnerUtils(c.getString("name"), c.getInt("id"));   

for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++) {
    items[i] = new SpinnerUtils(c.getString("name"), c.getInt("id"));                       
}

ArrayAdapter<SpinnerUtils> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerUtils> . 
                           (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);


adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

s.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where s is your spinner. To retrieve the id:

```
 SpinnerUtils d = items[position];
 int standard = d.getValue();
```

Create the above 2 lines within the `setOnItemSelectedListener` of the spinner to get the id.I have given you a rough idea.Hope it will work.